# Gettext Different Translation

Tags: php, gettext

I have a problem with gettext in PHP. Think of a situation where a word or expression in the source language can have different meanings.

For example: Word `A` word has two meanings; one is `B` and one is `C`. In a part of website we should use `B`. And in another part we should use `C`.

When we write `_('A')` How can ve get `B` or `C`? There should be a solid way to handle this.

Comment: Could you post a demonstration, and show the code you've already tried?

Comment: there nothing to write. Because i've already using. The problem is that i need more than one translation in same word.

Comment: Sorry, it's always good to show what you've already tried and explain why it didn't work. No-one is going to write it for you.

Comment: @BenM if you have a key-value list, what could he try to make having two same kays? This is not so much code, as standards related.

Answer (score 4):

Gettext supports so-called [message contexts](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Contexts.html). PHP doesn't have a native method for this, but [it can easily be implemented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php#89975).

Assuming we want to use the term “amount” in different contexts – in one context, it means “the count of a set of items”, in anonther context, it refers to “invoice amount”.

It works in several steps:

First: Instead of using the `gettext()` function, you would use a custom one; let's call it `contextGettext()`.

```php
echo contextGettext('amount', 'count of items');
echo contextGettext('amount', 'invoice amount');
```

This method looks like this:

```php
function contextGettext($string, $context)
{
    // http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.gettext.php#89975
    $contextString = "{$context}\004{$string}";
    $translation = gettext($contextString);
    return ($translation === $contextString) ? $string : $translation;
}
```

Note the `\004`: This is the separator which delimits the context identifier from the message string, as per gettext specification. (Nothing you need to really care about, just to know the background.)

When collecting translatable strings with the `xgettext` tool, you would add the following `--keyword` argument for the context-sensitive strings:

```bash
xgettext … --keyword="contextGettext:2c,1" …
```

Your `.po` file will then have the following entries:

```po
msgctxt "count of items"
msgid "amount"
msgstr ""

msgctxt "invoice amount"
msgid "amount"
msgstr ""
```

After translating the catalog, generating the `.mo` files and restarting your webserver, your web application will output the correct strings in the correct place.